# Error while trying to rotate polar plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

So I'm trying to rotate a polar plot in matlab however when I try to the suggested solution, `view(90,-90);`, `view(0,-90);` or other variations, I'm left with this

```
Error using matlab.graphics.axis.PolarAxes/set
PolarAxes View property must be [0 90].

Error in view>ViewCore (line 197)
    set(hAxes, 'View', [azIn, elIn]);

Error in view (line 75)
  ViewCore(hAxes, viewArgs{:});

Error in PolarPlotter (line 29)
view(0,-90);
```

Does anyone know any alternative to using the view command or if there's something that needs to be fixed in the matlab installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to rotate by a multiple of 90 degrees, you can set the rotation of a polar plot by setting the `ThetaZeroLocation`, which sets where on the plot the zero angle is located. By default this is set to `'left'` -- you can change this to one of `'left'`, `'right'`, `'bottom'`, or `'top'`. It is not possible using this method to set a rotation that is not a factor of 90 degrees, although there are workarounds to make this possible.

The reason that your rotation was not working appears to be due to a restriction imposed by MathWorks on the PolarAxes class. Due to this restriction, the view is fixed at `[0,90]`.

Comment: Great thanks! This worked just fine. As a pointer for anyone else doing this, it's done by adding ```pax = gca;
pax.ThetaZeroLocation = 'top';``` after the polar plot is created.

Comment: @JoshuaFrizzell This is true -- it is also possible to do this in a single statement as `set(gca,'ThetaZeroLocation','top')`.